# Why is .pop() deleting all values with the same index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that generates a dictionary containing `x` number of decks with 52 cards as tuples with a value and the card name:

```
decks = {
    'deck1':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),(1, 'Ace of Diamonds')...], 
    'deck2':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),...]
}
```

From there I want to randomly select a deck and a card in that deck, then remove that card from that deck alone. All of my attempts result in the tuples being deleted from all of the decks.

I have tried other methods to remove the card, but they all have the same result.

```py
def rand_Draw(decks):    # Receives dictionary of decks as input
    deck_Num = random.randrange(1,num_Decks+1,1)    # Selects deck's number
    deck = decks["deck"+str(deck_Num)]              # Selects deck
    card_Sel_Index = random.randrange(0,len(deck),1)    # Selects card's index

    card = deck.pop(card_Sel_Index)     # Save and remove card

    return card, deck_Num
```

Here is the deck making code:

```py
card_Dictionary = [(1,'Ace'),(2,'Two'),(3,'Three'),(4,'Four'),(5,'Five'),(6,'Six'),(7,'Seven'),(8,'Eight'),(9,'Nine'),(10,'Ten'),(10,'Jack'),(10,'King'),(10,'Queen')]
num_Decks = 5

def card_Creator(card_Dictionary, num_Decks):
    master_Deck = []
    for i in range(0,len(card_Dictionary),1):
        card = card_Dictionary[i]
        (value, type) = card
        hearts = suit_Creator(value, type, "Hearts")
        diamonds = suit_Creator(value, type, "Diamonds")
        spades = suit_Creator(value, type, "Spades")
        clubs = suit_Creator(value, type, "Clubs")
        set = [hearts] + [diamonds] + [spades] + [clubs]
        master_Deck += set

    # The hearts, diamonds, etc. can make a deck with Deck1 = Hearts + Diamonds + Spades + Clubs
    decks = {}
    for i in range (1,num_Decks+1):
        decks["deck" + str(i)] = master_Deck

    return decks # Decks is stored in a dictionary so I can call on a deck

def suit_Creator(value, type, suit):
    output = (value, type + " of " + suit)
    return output
```

I hoped that after calling this once that one deck would be reduced to length 51, but all decks created are reduced to length 51 with the same card index removed (identical cards).

Comment: could you post more code, like what is the value passed to `decks`? I have a suspicion that all the dictionaries in decks are just referencing the same object underneath.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion the decks-generating code is not `decks = {
    'deck1':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),(1, 'Ace of Diamonds')...], 
    'deck2':[((1, 'Ace of Hearts')),...]
}`. Please show how you create the decks, not just their value.

Comment: I concur with @new-dev-123 and @Amadan. One way to test for situation is to check `decks['deck1'] is decks['deck2']` is equal to `True`. If that is the case, you need to look at the way you create `decks`.

Comment: Does `deck = decks["deck"+str(deck_Num)]` create a copy of the deck dictionary, or is it like a view that will change the value of the original dictionary?

Comment: Also, `'deck2':[((1, 'Ace of Hearts')),...]` should be `'deck2':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),...]` right? I assume that's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python assignment does not copy objects, but shares them. You only have one deck, the `master_Deck`, which is referenced under different names in `decks`. It's like looking at a box directly and through a mirror: if you remove a thing from the box, it's gone in the mirror image, too, because the mirror doesn't copy :-)

Some programming languages copy objects and arrays upon assignment, making it somewhat difficult to handle shared references. You might find Python's behavior unexpected if you worked with such a language before.

Comment: Thanks, that is very new to me, I only have past coding experience in matlab where I don't think that's a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it's all right, maybe you're using a global variable called `num_Decks` and the code failed for some reason. I've added a `len` in your function and worked fine to me.

```
def rand_Draw(decks):    # Receives dictionary of decks as input
    num_Decks = len(decks) # Maybe you forgot this
    deck_Num = random.randrange(1,num_Decks+1,1)    # Selects deck's number
    deck = decks["deck"+str(deck_Num)]              # Selects deck
    card_Sel_Index = random.randrange(0,len(deck),1)    # Selects card's index
    card = deck.pop(card_Sel_Index) # Save and remove card
    print(deck)
    return card, deck_Num
```

My input and ouput:

```
>>> decks = {
    'deck1':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),(1, 'Ace of Diamonds')], 
    'deck2':[(1, 'Ace of Hearts'),(1, 'Ace of Diamonds')]
}
>>> rand_Draw(decks)
[(1, 'Ace of Diamonds')] <<< This are from the print at middle of function
((1, 'Ace of Hearts'), 2) <<< Your return
```

EDIT: As suggested, you should do `rand_Draw(decks.copy())` to not change global decks variable.

Comment: RE: the edit, I think that's the purpose of drawing a random card, though - to return a card and remove it from the deck. Hence why .pop() is used.

Comment: @PeptideWitch I agree with you. But maybe he should keep all cards just to safety or do something else (like reset the game). Thanks for comment!

Comment: Doing a .copy() would probably be a good idea. You were right about the code it works with your inputs, so I guess it must be an issue with my inputs.